# How to make XSLT emit an angle bracket?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, entity

I have an XSL transform that merges information from several XML files (secondaries) into another XML file (primary). The output consists of markdown. I need to make the primary XML file generate an HTML tag in the markdown file. How do I do that?

The primary XML file has a stylesheet with definitions like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
  <!ENTITY xlt     "&amp;lt;" >
  <!ENTITY xgt     "&amp;gt;" >
]>
```

But this makes the transform change `&xlt;a id="..."&xgt;` into `&lt;a id="..."&gt;`, and when the page is opened in a browser it composes `<a id="...">`. I want to make the HTML *contain* `<a id="...">`, and compose nothing, but define a label.

I tried to define the stylesheet like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
  <!ENTITY xlt     "&amp;lt;" >
  <!ENTITY xgt     "&amp;gt;" >
  <!ENTITY xlab    "<" >
  <!ENTITY xrab    ">" >
]>
```

...and use it like this in the primary XML: `&xlab;a id="..."&xrab;`.

But this got me the following error from the XML processor (Saxon-HE 9.9.1.5N from Saxonica):

```
Error on line 238 column 7 of <primary XML file):
  SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: XML document structures must start and end within
  the same entity.
```

(Line 238 column 7 is the position immediately after `&xlab;`.)

The transform seems to be upset by an entity that resolves to an angle bracket. If I replace the stylesheet with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
  <!ENTITY xlt     "&amp;lt;" >
  <!ENTITY xgt     "&amp;gt;" >
  <!ENTITY xlab    "[" >
  <!ENTITY xrab    "]" >
]>
```

...I get well-behaved output: `[a id="..."]`. But that, of course, is not an HTML tag.

Comment: Can you show an example of your expected output? If you are having issues with the fact that angle brackets are serialized as escaped entities in an XML file, well that is what it is supposed to do. If you use XML tools to read that XML it won't matter. If you are just string parsing the XML, you are doing it wrong and will get errors. If you *really* need the text not to be escaped, there are some tricks to serializing to ensure that it uses CDATA, but it's more helpful if you provide an example of your desired output.

Comment: I must be missing something, because an example of my expected output, as I understand that request, is in the question: `<a id="...">`, where dot-dot-dot represents an arbitrary label name. The tag is to be embedded in a markdown file, but the other contents of the file would have no bearing on the problem.

Comment: Trying to ask an XSLT question without showing your XSLT almost certain to waste your time and ours.  Please read *[ask]*, [edit] your question, and include a **[mcve]** illustrating what's working and what's not.  Also, having accepted only a single answer out of 38 questions over 7 years is another sign that you're not using this site as well as you could.

Comment: I repeat, the "example," to the extent that one is necessary, is in the original question. I will restate the question once more: _How can I make an XSLT emit an HTML tag?_

Answer (score 0):

An XSLT stylesheet produces a **result tree** which is then serialized, typically as XML, HTML, or text. The transformation doesn't directly produce lexical markup.

To produce markdown, I think your best bet is to serialize using the text output method. If the markdown is to include fragments of HTML, then you may find the XSLT 3.0 serialize() function useful to generate these.

Comment: I may not have explained my problem clearly: _how to make the XSLT generate an HTML tag_. The XSLT is otherwise debugged and producing markdown output perfectly.

Comment: With the text output method, you can either construct the HTML tag "by hand", or you can (in 3.0) call serialize() to generate it, and copy the resulting string to the markdown output.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me which output method (text, xml, html) and result format you use. If the output is Markdown, do browsers render Markdown by now or what does the remark "when the page is opened in a browser it composes " refer to? I would agree with the evaluation given in Michael Kay's answer, if you want to produce Markdown with XSLT 3 then use the `text` output method and any XML or HTML tags you want to insert you produce by using the XPath 3.1 `serialize` function on nodes you have in the input or create in the XSLT.

So for instance with the XML input as

```
<section>
    <h2>Example</h2>
    <div class="example">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>col 1</th>
                    <th>col 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>foo</td>
                    <td>bar</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</section>
```

and the stylesheet using the text output method and the `serialize` function to serialize nodes to text the XSLT sample (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDko)

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="h2">## {.}
</xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="div[@class = 'example']">```html
{serialize(node(), map { 'method' : 'html', 'indent' : false() })}
```
</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
````

creates the output

````
## Example
```html

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>col 1</th>
                    <th>col 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>foo</td>
                    <td>bar</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    
```
````

rendered as

### Example

```html
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>col 1</th>
                    <th>col 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>foo</td>
                    <td>bar</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

And in general, in XML which XSLT is, if you want to insert markup as plain text, use a CDATA section `<![CDATA[<a id="a1"></a>]]>`.